# How to authenticate, with azure devops services, using SAML via on premise standalone java application?

Tags: azure-devops, azure, tfs

We have a network where azure DevOps services can be used by logging in via SAML. There is an independent java application in that same network.

Can anyone please point out a way that this java application can get authenticated to Azure DevOps services via SAML, without any manual intervention?

PS: I've explored a lot of blogs but I couldn't find what I need specifically. Closest I got, was to register my java application as a AD tenant, but in our use case this can't be done.

Is there any other alternative? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly sizable [range of authentication options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops), based upon what you have said you are looking for a non-interactive login which rules out some options, and leaves the following:

- [Device Profile](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/DeviceProfileSample) - probably not ideal for you given you would need to find a way to this in Java as the examples are few and far between and mostly written in C#.
- [TFS Application](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/ClientLibraryConsoleAppSample) - again not ideal given you would need to either find someone who has written a 3rd party client library for Java or write one yourself.
- Azure DevOps Extension - while you could write an Azure DevOps extension, and use that to access Azure DevOps it's a lot of work and potentially would expose security issues.

Given that we have probably ruled out non-interactive login to Azure DevOps you could also explore one of the two following options:

- **Interactive Logins** - is there an option in your environment from forcing the user to authenticate with Azure DevOps using [OAuth](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) then capture the token for non-interactive use?  This is quite a common pattern with GitHub, GitLab and Bitbucket.
- **[Personal Access Tokens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)** - mostly this would be abusing a feature of Azure DevOps as these are designed for users not applications, although it could work in your constrained environment.
- **Non-interactive Login using your Identity Provider** - you haven't detailed who your Identity Provider is, but it is possible it supports authentication using Client Certificates, Shared Secrets, etc. which would give you a SAML token which could be exchanged for an Azure DevOps Access token.

Hope those help.